# Filtering an array in react with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to filter one array so that the objects will display if they match one of the options at the `filterOptions` (another array).

**Example:** If `filterOptions` contains the string `big` it should show the objects with `sizes` containing the string `big`

However, I'm not sure how to split `data.sizes` correctly so it can use this data to filter with, how can I do this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-ellis-dplhg

```
export const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {sizes: 'big,small',},
    {sizes: 'medium,small'},
    {sizes: 'small,big',},
    {sizes: 'big',},
    {sizes: 'medium',}
  ];

  const filterOptions = ['big', 'small'];
  const splitData = data.map(items => items.sizes.split(','));

  return(
    <div>
      {console.log(splitData)}
      {data.filter(items => items.sizes.includes(filterOptions))
           .map(item => <div>{item.sizes}<br /></div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So in this case only show sizes containing *both* big and small, or does `sizes: 'big'` pass even though 'small' isn't in it?

Comment: my two cents suggestion: sizes should be an array. sizes: ['big', 'small', 'medium']. In this way, you don't have to split it and it is clearer. Not to mention, sizes: 'small, __space__big, __space__ __space__medium__space____space' will break your code if you don't split and trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
{data.filter(i => i.sizes.split(",").some(size => filterOptions.includes(size)))
     .map(item => <div>{item.sizes}<br/></div>)}
```

## Example of the filter result:

```js
const data = [
  {sizes: 'big,small'},
  {sizes: 'medium,small'},
  {sizes: 'small,big'},
  {sizes: 'big'},
  {sizes: 'medium'}
];

const filterOptions = ['big','small'];

let res = data.filter(
    i => i.sizes.split(",").some(
        size => filterOptions.includes(size)
    )
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, for your particular set of sizes (`"small"`, `"big"` and `"medium"`), where there are no string that is also substring of another string, you can go with the next filter using a regular expression constructed from the `filterOptions` array:

```js
const data = [
  {sizes: 'big,small'},
  {sizes: 'medium,small'},
  {sizes: 'small,big'},
  {sizes: 'big'},
  {sizes: 'medium'}
];

const filterOptions = ['big','small'];

let res = data.filter(
    ({sizes}) => new RegExp(filterOptions.join("|")).test(sizes)
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, in your context of code:

```
{data.filter(({sizes}) => new RegExp(filterOptions.join("|")).test(sizes))
     .map(item => <div>{item.sizes}<br/></div>)}
```

Answer (score 2):

this answer can fit as many filter options as possible

```
data.filter(items => items.sizes.split(',').find(size => filterOptions.includes(size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might go about it (there are a lot of different ways to achieve your result though):

```js
const data = [
  { sizes: 'big,small', },
  { sizes: 'medium,small' },
  { sizes: 'small,big', },
  { sizes: 'big', },
  { sizes: 'medium', }
];

const filterOptions = [ "big", "small" ];
const filterData = data.filter( ( { sizes } ) => {
  for ( const filter of filterOptions ) {
    if ( sizes.includes( filter ) ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
} );

console.log( filterData );
```

This is assuming of course you don't want the data sizes to contain *both* `filterOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```js
const data = [
    {
      sizes: 'big,small',
    },
    {
      sizes: 'medium,small'
    },
    {
      sizes: 'small,big',
    },
    {
      sizes: 'big',
    },
    {
      sizes: 'medium',
    }
  ];

const filterOptions = ['big','small'];

const filterData = data.filter( d => filterOptions.every(f => d.sizes.split(',').includes(f)));

console.log(filterData);
```